# Wix Using Edit Control

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to use the Edit Control within an Dialog. When I use this Control I always get an error. The error code is 2228.

if I use a different control(Text) it works!

here is my code:

```
<UI Id="myUI">
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
  <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
  <Dialog Id="myDlg" Height="400" Width="550" Title="Uninstall Sample UI">
    <Control Id="myEdit" Type="Edit" Property="USER_NAME" Height="17" Width="100" X="50" Y="50" />
  </Dialog>
</UI>
</Fragment>
```

And I also have a Reference to `WixUIExtension.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 2228 is shown because the control is not defined correctly, resulting in an incorrect query for the MSI database.

Try setting the Indirect and Text attributes:

```
<Control Id="myEdit" Type="Edit" Property="USER_NAME" Height="17" Width="100" X="50" Y="50" Indirect="yes" Text="[USER_NAME]"/>
```

This way the editbox value is handled by its property.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, but still I get the same error! Any other suggestions??

Comment: @Tim: Can you please make sure you have added the references to WIX. Please add WixUtilExtension too and give a try

Comment: @Sunil thank you for your answer! I just tried it and since i've added this reference it works fine. The crazy thing is, that now it works, even if I remove all the references !?!? strange!! But still Thank you very much!!!!